# Em R, como descobrir se dois vertices são adjacentes a partir de uma matriz de adjacencia

Tags: r, algoritmo, matriz

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Essa é a matriz de adjacencia, como descobrir(implementar um algoritmo) se os vertices 2 e 3 são adjacentes utilizando o R?

Comment: Tem algum problema na digitação da sua "matriz". Você precisa editar a questão. Outro ponto é que o problema que você está querendo resolver não está muito claro. Elabore melhor.

Comment: (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (3,4) (3,5). Apos importar como matriz de adjacencia, pretendo criar um algoritmo para descobrir se os vertices 2 e 3 sao adjacentes.

Comment: Qual é a dimensão dessa matriz?

Comment: 5x5. So para reforçar, ela é formada por 0 e 1. E os vertices são: 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5

Comment: do jeito que você apresentou a matriz, como uma sequência de números, não dá para saber quem são os elementos. Por exemplo: quais são os elementos da linha 3 coluna 5 e ou linha 2 coluna 3?

Comment: Vou tentar descrever por aqui. 1ª linha: [0 1 1 0 0] 2ª[1 0 1 0 0], 3ª[1 1 0 1 1], 4ª[0 0 1 0 0], 5ª[0 0 1 0 0]. Os indices das linhas e colunas são de 1 a 5.

Comment: Você precisa editar o texto da questão. Coloque como código e digite novamente lá. Logo abaixo das tags tem três palavras: compartilhar editar sinalizar. Clique em editar.

Answer (score 5):

Bom, sua pergunta está um pouco melhor mas para seu exemplo ser realmente reprodutível você deveria fornecer a matriz em um formato pronto para o R, tal que quem fosse responder só precisaria copiar e colar. De qualquer forma segue a resposta.

**Conjunto Mínimo**

Aqui vou recriar sua matriz no `R`:

```
g <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0), nrow = 5)
```

o que resulta na seguinte matriz

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    0
```

**Usando o igraph**

O `R` conta com [igraph](https://igraph.org/) que lhe permite fazer praticamente tudo com grafos, inclusive os plots de grafos a partir das matrizes de adjacência:

```
library(igraph)

## Cria o grafo a partir da matriz de adjacências g
G <- as.undirected(graph.adjacency(g, weighted = T))

## Plot do grafo
plot(G)
```

o que resulta no seguinte grafo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E por fim você pode utilizar a função `as_adj_list()`:

```
al <- as_adj_list(G, mode="out")

[[1]]
+ 2/5 vertices, from 7a41c18:
[1] 2 3

[[2]]
+ 2/5 vertices, from 7a41c18:
[1] 1 3

[[3]]
+ 4/5 vertices, from 7a41c18:
[1] 1 2 4 5

[[4]]
+ 1/5 vertex, from 7a41c18:
[1] 3

[[5]]
+ 1/5 vertex, from 7a41c18:
[1] 3
```

Veja que cada elemento da lista é relacionado a um dos vértices e dentro da lista estão os vértices vizinhos. No caso da sua pergunta, para saber se os vértices 2 e 3 são vizinhos basta procurar os vizinhos do vértice 2, na posição dois da lista:

```
> al[[2]]
+ 2/5 vertices, from 7a41c18:
[1] 1 3
```

portanto os vértice 1 e 3.

**Construindo um teste de adjacência**

De posse do grafo e da lista de adjacências é possível criar uma função que testa a adjacência de dois vértices quaisquer:

```
sao_adj <- function(x,y,al) {

  ## Testa se x e y são adjacentes
  return(y %in% al[[x]])

}
```

E vamos testar para um caso onde ocorre a adjacência e um caso onde não ocorre:

```
> sao_adj(x = 1, y = 2, al = al)
[1] TRUE
> sao_adj(x = 5, y = 2, al = al)
[1] FALSE
> sao_adj(x = 1, y = 4, al = al)
[1] FALSE
> sao_adj(x = 3, y = 1, al = al)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Obrigado! Sou novo por aqui, estou ajustando...Ajudou bastante, porem a ideia é encontrar ou elaborar um algoritmo que busque identificar se dois vertices quais quer sao adjacentes...

Comment: @Tiago veja que inicialmente a minha resposta já respondeu sua pergunta. De qualquer forma agora você tem uma função que testa adjacência entre dois vértices quaisquer.